# OpenLDAP 2.4.44 Authentication on CentOS/RHEL 7

Tags: centos, redhat, openldap, pam

I have OpenLDAP 2.4.44 running on CentOS 7.4 with a "tester" user added. I can query the user and change the password, but when authenticating with the GNOME login screen is always rejected. I used this [guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html) to set things up.

The LDIF files I used to set the system up are as follows:

**db.ldif**

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=ldapadm,dc=example

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: <omitted>
```

**monitor.ldif**

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=ldapadm,dc=example" read by * none
```

**base.ldif**

```
dn: dc=example
dc: example
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain

dn: cn=ldapadm,dc=example
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: ldapadm
description: LDAP Manager

dn: ou=People,dc=example
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Groups,dc=example
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups
```

**certs.ldif** (these certs were created and owner/group changed to ldap:ldap)

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/managerldapcert.pem

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/managerldapkey.pem
```

**tester.ldif**

```
dn: uid=tester,ou=People,dc=example
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: tester
uid: tester
uidNumber: 9001
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/tester
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: Tester Account
userPassword: {crypt}x
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
```

To show the account information for the user:

```
ldapsearch -x cn=tester -b dc=example
```

The response is as follows:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=tester
# requesting: ALL
#

# tester, People, example
dn: uid=tester,ou=People,dc=example
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: tester
uid: tester
uidNumber: 9001
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/tester
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: Tester Account
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
userPassword:: <omitted>

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

I can change the password using the following:

```
ldappasswd -H ldap:/// -x -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=example" -W -S "uid=tester,ou=People,dc=example"
```

This prompts for the new user password (twice) and the LDAP root password, then exits. I can observe that the password changed by re-querying using ldapsearch (where the userPassword:: section changes).

I can log into the LDAP account to verify the password by using:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h ldapi:/// -p 389 -D "uid=tester,ou=People,dc=example" -x -W
```

I then set up authconfig using:

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=servername.example --ldapbasedn="dc=example" --enablemkhomedir --update
```

But, when I try and use the CentOS GNOME login screen, the password is rejected.

In */var/log/secure* I see the following:

```
pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=tester
pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): received for user tester: 6 (Permission denied)
```

Things I have tried without success:

- Disabling SELinux (as a test, not because its a possible solution)
- Setting `FORCELEGACY=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig` per this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/672203/fedora-21-pam-sss-authentication-failure-permission-denied)
- Using `system-config-authentication` and other suggestions at this [link](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-pam.html)
- Installing the certificate I created using the suggestion [here](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-system-use-existing-ldap-directory-service-user-group-information/)

My question is... how is CentOS 7 trying to log in (and how can I emulate the login attempt using ldapwhoami), and how can this be better debugged/logged? Does my user DN seem reasonable (using uid instead of cn for the first entry; I've seen it done both ways in different guides)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed `sssd`?

Comment: sssd-1.15.2-50 is installed